# Failed to seed database with data with a relation using code first approach

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

The database has two tables Coach and CoachType (see below). It is possible to create this two tables with code first (Add-Migrations and then Update-Database).

```
public class Coach
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FK_CoachType_Id")]
        public int CoachTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual CoachType coachtype { get; set; }
    }

public class CoachType
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to seed the data with some default data, it show the error message:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_coaches_coachtypes_CoachTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.CoachType", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Here is my code with the data to fill the tables:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CoachType>().HasData(new CoachType
        {
            CoachTypeId = 1,
            Name = "Name"
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Coach>().HasData(new Coach
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Name",
            CoachTypeId = 1
        });`enter code here`
```

I looked on Google and tried some stuff but I keep getting that message.

Comment: Have you made it to migrate your model in the first place? Because your `ForeignKey` attribute contains a navigation that does not exist in your model and when trying to create a migration EF stops you with an error. You must change it to `[ForeignKey("coachtype")]`

Comment: @rad Yes without data the database and tables are created with the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The `Id` column of `CoachType` table is auto-generated so whatever value you assign to its `Id`, it is ignored, therefore, when `CoachType` is inserted, there is a chance that the inserted record `Id` won't be `1`. Consequently, when trying to insert the `Coach` with `CoachTypeId` equal to `1`, it throws foreign key conflict error.
One possible solution is to make the `Id` column of `CoachType` non-identity.
Also, I don't know why you have written `CoachTypeId` instead of `Id`.